# Перехват сообщений отправленных только из этого же приложения на другом устройстве с эти мже приложением

Tags: java, android, android-studio, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста:
1) как можно реализовать приложение, которое отлавливает сообщения отправленные только с такого же приложения на другом устройстве (RECEIVE_SMS)
2) как запретить отображение SMS, отправленных из приложения в стандартном приложение (Сообщения) на базе android